# Problema con petición http en AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs, http, url, get

Intentando realizar una petición asíncrona para mostrar un listado en pantalla con AngularJS, me encuentro con el problema de que los datos no son mostrados. ¿A qué puede deberse? En consola no aparece ningún error. Así se ve el listado: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Practicando AngularJS">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS - http</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FirstController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
            <p>
                {{post.body}}
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js:**

```
angular.module("Practicando AngularJS", [])
    .controller("FirstController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.posts = [];
        $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.posts = data;
            })
            //.error(function(err) {

            //});
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La llamada Get si te esta trayendo la información? Si es así, como se mira la estructura de la respuesta?

Comment: Object
data: Array(100)
0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", body: "quia et suscipit↵suscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}
1: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse", body: "est rerum tempore vitae↵sequi sint nihil reprehend…aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"}
2: {userId: 1, id: 3, title: "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut", body: "et iusto sed quo iure↵voluptatem occaecati omnis e…↵molestiae porro eius odio et labore et"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver, accedías al objeto `response` (tu `data`) directamente, y eso no es válido, ya que el objeto response, no contiene únicamente los datos, si no más cosas. [Consulta aquí su definición oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response)

> Es decir, he cambiado el nombre `data` por `response` para darle más
>   claridad, y así, verás que realmente hay que acceder a `response.data`

Puedes comprobarlo con este script:

```js
angular.module("Practicando AngularJS", []).controller("FirstController", function ($scope, $http) 
{
        $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .then(function(response) {
                //response es un objeto que tiene más cosas que los datos, como el estado de la respuesta, etc.
                console.log("EN LA CONSOLA PUEDES VER TODO EL OBJETO RESPONSE");
                console.log(response);

                //tienes que acceder a Response.data
                $scope.posts = response.data;
            })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Practicando AngularJS" ng-controller="FirstController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
            <p>
                {{post.body}}
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```